# Creating a polynomial from Int text file. 

Tags: java, linked-list, polynomial-math

I'm reading in a .txt file to create polynomials. I am having trouble actually printing the polynomials (after they've been put into the linked list). I'm not really sure how to go about 'linking' the linked list and the polynomial method...

Text File:

```
P1 = 3 5 1 -1 0 8
P2 = 5 6 2 -1 1 7 0 -4
p3 = p1 + p2
p4 = p3 - p1
```

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Polynomial {
    public Term first;
    public Term last;
    private int[] coef; // coefficients
    private int deg; // degree of polynomial (0 for the zero polynomial)

    // a * x^b
    public Polynomial(int a, int b) {
        coef = new int[b + 1];
        coef[b] = a;
        deg = degree();
    }

    // return the degree of this polynomial (0 for the zero polynomial)
    public int degree() {
        int d = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < coef.length; i++)
            if (coef[i] != 0)
                d = i;
        return d;
    }

    // return c = a + b
    public Polynomial plus(Polynomial b) {
        Polynomial a = this;
        Polynomial c = new Polynomial(0, Math.max(a.deg, b.deg));
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.deg; i++)
            c.coef[i] += a.coef[i];
        for (int i = 0; i <= b.deg; i++)
            c.coef[i] += b.coef[i];
        c.deg = c.degree();
        return c;
    }

    // return (a - b)
    public Polynomial minus(Polynomial b) {
        Polynomial a = this;
        Polynomial c = new Polynomial(0, Math.max(a.deg, b.deg));
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.deg; i++)
            c.coef[i] += a.coef[i];
        for (int i = 0; i <= b.deg; i++)
            c.coef[i] -= b.coef[i];
        c.deg = c.degree();
        return c;
    }

    // convert to string representation
    public String toString() {
        if (deg == 0)
            return "" + coef[0];
        if (deg == 1)
            return coef[1] + "x + " + coef[0];
        String s = coef[deg] + "x^" + deg;
        for (int i = deg - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (coef[i] == 0)
                continue;
            else if (coef[i] > 0)
                s = s + " + " + (coef[i]);
            else if (coef[i] < 0)
                s = s + " - " + (-coef[i]);
            if (i == 1)
                s = s + "x";
            else if (i > 1)
                s = s + "x^" + i;
        }
        return s;
    }

    // test client
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Welcome message
        System.out
                .println("Welcome! The following program processes single-variable polynomials represented as linked lists.\n"
                        + "Test Data will appear below, and is also saved to a text file (userSpecification.txt) \n"
                        + "-------------------------------" + "\n");

        String content = new String();
        String name = new String();
        File file = new File("polynomialTest.txt");
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                name = sc.next();
                content = sc.nextLine();

                // ..just checking things as they come in.
                System.out.println("name " + name + "  content " + content);

                list.add(content);

            }

            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\nProgram terminated Safely...");
        }

        Iterator<String> i = list.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(name + i.next() + "\n");

        }

    private class Term {
        int coef;
        int expo;
        Term next;

        Term(int coef, int expo, Term n) {
            this.coef = coef;
            this.expo = expo;
            this.next = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Desired output:

```
P1 = 5X^3 – 4X + 8 
P2 = 6X^5 -2X^2 +7X -4 
P3 = 6X^5 +5X^3 -2X^2 +3X +4 
P4 = 6X^5 -2X^2 +7X -4
```

Output right now:

```
Project #2
Welcome! The following program processes single-variable polynomials represented as linked lists.
-------------------------------

P1 = 3 5 1 -1 0 8

P2 = 5 6 2 -1 1 7 0 -4

p3 = p1 + p2

p4 = p3 - p1

[P1 = 3 5 1 -1 0 8, P2 = 5 6 2 -1 1 7 0 -4, p3 = p1 + p2, p4 = p3 - p1]
```

Comment: It must be: P1 = 5X^3 - X + 8, your first equation is incorrect, or your input data is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not so much worried about the number as I am getting the polynomials to actually display (like the expected output). Good catch though, I'll change that!

Answer (score 1):

do you understand the concept of a `LinkedList` and its use in your program?  From what I gathered from your code (which, if you want more answers, should be very concise and contain only the code that is absolutely required for your program to run), you have this `Term` class, which is an implementation of a `LinkedList`, within this `Polynomial` class which is basically just holding the `Term` class and not doing much with it and instead is taking care of all of your code by itself.  What you should do is think of the `Term` itself as a collection of nodes representing the polynomial expression.  In your `main` function you should be reading in the variables, making them into `Term` instantiations, and adding them on to a root `Term` instantiation (one per polynomial expression) as more nodes.  When you are adding `Term`s (now full polynomial expressions) together, all you have to do is cycle through and add together all of the ones with the same exponent.